# Changing colour and dimensions of JPanel not working

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I created a JPanel that contains 9 instances of the `ItemTest` class in a grid formation.

The `ItemTest` class contains its own JPanel, a checkbox, and some text.  It is used to represent different items that can be purchased.  I would like to be able to change the size and colour of the JPanel components belonging to the ItemTest class.

The setSize method and setForeground methods don't seem to work here. `this.setSize(100,100)` and `this.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(80,80,90))` have no affect on the JPanel.

```java
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class ItemTest extends JPanel{

    static JPanel secondPanel = new JPanel();

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8013287075740780359L;

    static JCheckBox selectBox;

    static GraphicsConfiguration gc;

    static JFrame frame = new JFrame(gc);

    ItemTest(String name, double cost){

        JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel();
        this.add(nameLabel);
        nameLabel.setText(name);

        selectBox = new JCheckBox("$"+cost);

        this.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(80, 80, 90));
        this.setSize(100, 100);
        this.add(selectBox);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setTitle("Program");
        frame.setSize(1000,800);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(new java.awt.Color(100,100,110));

        secondPanel.setBounds(345,40,640,700);
        secondPanel.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(90,90,100));
        secondPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3,50,50));
        secondPanel.setVisible(true);
        secondPanel.getComponents();
        frame.add(secondPanel);

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i ++) {
            secondPanel.add(new ItemTest("T-Shirt",50));
            System.out.println("test");
        }
    }
}
```

---

EDIT:

After reading with some suggestions to improve my code I changed my class a bit.

```java
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class ItemTest extends JPanel{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8013287075740780359L;

    static GraphicsConfiguration gc;
    static JFrame frame = new JFrame(gc);

    ItemTest(String name, double cost){

        JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel();
        this.add(nameLabel);
        nameLabel.setText(name);


        JCheckBox selectBox = new JCheckBox("$"+cost);
        this.add(selectBox);

        //Changes colour of the text, but I want that to remain black.  I'm looking to change the colour of the actuall JPanel.
        selectBox.setForeground(Color.red);
        nameLabel.setForeground(Color.red);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        frame.setTitle("Program");
        frame.setSize(1000,800);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout( new GridBagLayout() );
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(new java.awt.Color(100,100,110));
        frame.setVisible(true);

        JPanel secondPanel = new  JPanel();
        //secondPanel.setBounds(345,40,640,700);
        secondPanel.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(90,90,100));
        secondPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3,50,50));
        secondPanel.setVisible(true);
        secondPanel.getComponents();
        frame.add(secondPanel);

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i ++) {
            secondPanel.add(new ItemTest("T-Shirt",50));
        }
    }
}
```

Changing the `setBounds` method removed my preferred size of the JPanel, so now all of the items are in the centre of the window, instead of my previous design where they were contained in a jpanel off to the side.

Using

```java
selectBox.setForeground(Color.red);
nameLabel.setForeground(Color.red);
```

Will set text colour to red.  I would like to change the background colour of the JPanel, and keep the text colour as black.

I would like the items to be placed on the panel off to the side as in my original code with dimensions say 50x50.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
static JCheckBox selectBox;
```

Don't use static variables Swing components should be instances variables defined in your ItemTest class.

```
this.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(80, 80, 90));
```

Setting the foreground on a JPanel does nothing because then is no custom painting on a JPanel.

You would need to set the foreground on the JLabel and JCheckbox.

```
this.setSize(100, 100);
```

Don't use setSize(...). As you have noticed it will be ignored.

Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. The default layout for a JPanel is the FlowLayout. The JLabel and JCheckBox will both be displayed at their preferred size.

If you want extra space on the panel then you can use an `EmptyBorder`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Borders](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) for more information and working examples.

```
frame.setLayout(null);
secondPanel.setBounds(345,40,640,700);
```

Don't use a null layout and setBounds(...).

Instead use something like:

```
frame.setLayout( new GridBagLayout() );
```

The size of the panel will automatically be determined by the components you add to the panel.

Edits:

> I'm looking to change the colour of the actuall JPanel

Then you change the background of the panel using `setBackground(...)`, not setForeground(...).

> , so now all of the items are in the centre of the window, instead of my previous design where they were contained in a jpanel off to the side.

Yes, that is the default behaviour of the GridBagLayout. If you don't like that then you can use a different layout manager on the frame. Read the tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). The easiest might be the `FlowLayout`. You can specify the alignment to be left aligned.

> with dimensions say 50x50.

Don't use random numbers. You have no idea if the text of the label and check box can be displayed in 50 pixels. I already told you how to make the panel size bigger. Read the tutorial on Borders!!!

```
static GraphicsConfiguration gc;
static JFrame frame = new JFrame(gc);
```

You are still using static variables. Get rid of them they are not needed.

```
frame.setVisible(true);
```

This should be the last statement AFTER all the components have been added to the frame. Actually the code should be:

```
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible( true );
```

Then all the components will be display nicely at their preferred size.

Read the tutorial each section in the tutorial has working examples which you can download and play with. The tutorial will show you how to better structure your code.

Comment: `nameLabel.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(80, 80, 90));` `selectBox.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(80, 80, 90));` Setting the foreground colour of the JLabel instance and JCheckbox doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: …and `frame.setVisible(true);` should be the *last* thing of the `main` method, not the first. As every subsequent manipulation is violating the *single-thread* rule. Or perform the entire setup in another method invoked on the EDT via `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`. But generally, if you change the component hierarchy after opening the window, you have to trigger layouting or repainting manually. Since this can cause visible artifacts, you should only do this when dynamic changes are actually intended. Which brings us back to the “`frame.setVisible(true);` should be the last thing” rule.

Comment: @Hydra   *Setting the foreground colour of the JLabel instance and JCheckbox doesn't seem to change anything* 1) Pick a color like `Color.RED` so the text will stand out. 2) if that doesn't help then post a  [mre] showing how you have incorporated all the suggestions that have been made.